# Need to Change iOS app name/icon without affecting certification/provisioning

Tags: ios, xcode, icons, rename, ios-provisioning

I have a development app that I'd like to change the app's display name and change/add the default display icon (for ios phone).  I'm being careful since I do not want to re-do any of the certificate/provisioning.  I current have my demo app loaded on my phone with it's default name/ launch icon.

CHANGING DISPLAY NAME:
Other posts indicate this may be as simple as changing the bundle display name defined in the ***myfilename-info.plist*** file, that can be modified in a drop down menu/list, and is located in the Supporting File folder (XCode 6).  Right now it shows Bundle Display Name is ${PRODUCT_NAME}.  Should I edit this file/entry and which format should be used?  There is also a Bundle Identifier in the file/list but I'm guessing I should not touch that.

CHANGING LAUNCH ICON:
I'd like to change the launcher icon.  I saw an old post for XCode 4 but I wanted to check how to do it with XCode 6.

Thanks for the help!  I'm being cautious so I do not mess up my provisioning/certification that I've already been working with on this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the bundle display name, you have mentioned that correct. Just change  ${PRODUCT_NAME} with your required name in info.plist and save the file

For Launch Icon you can use xcassets and just drag the drop the images

just create a new set first and start drag drop
[image]

[image]

[image]

**NOTE**: No need to redo the provisioning and certification process